# Django UnicodeDecodeError in base_mixins

Tags: python, django

I'm having some issues POSTing an image to a Django API endpoint to populate an ImageField for a chat messaging program.  It seems that the request encounters a UnicodeDecodeError in django even before reaching my code when making a POST request to the endpoint with either PNG or JPG images.  I am unsure of how to get past this error so the request can be handled correctly and a new message created on the backend with an image in the photo field of the model.

The endpoint works as intended if posting non-file fields.

Model:

```py
class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    ...

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_message_upload_path,
                              null=True, blank=True)
```

Routing (using routers.DefaultRouter()):

```py
...
router.register(r'chatmessages', ChatMessageViewSet, base_name='chatmessages')
urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^api/v2/', include((router.urls, 'tradepros'), namespace='v2')),
...
]
```

View (This code is never reached and the print statement at the top never printed):

```py
class ChatMessageViewSet(LoggingMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("CALLING SERIALIZER")
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        instance = serializer.save()
        if 'message_image' in request.FILES:
            instance.photo = request.FILES['message_image']
            instance.message = "Photo attached, please update your TradePros app to see."
            instance.save()

        cache.delete('chatroom_tradepro_%s' % instance.room.pk)
        cache.delete('chatroom_tradeuser_%s' % instance.room.pk)
        cache.delete('chatrooms_tradepro_%s' % instance.room.tradepro.pk)
        cache.delete('chatrooms_tradeuser_%s' % instance.room.tradeuser.pk)

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Serializer:

```
class ChatMessageSerializer(FlexibleSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Chat messages, with only ID for users.
    """
    profile_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_profile_image(self, message):
        if message.tradepro:
            return message.room.tradepro.user.tradeuser.profile_image.url
        else:
            return message.room.tradeuser.profile_image.url

    class Meta:
        model = ChatMessage
        fields = ('id', 'room', 'tradepro', 'tradeuser', 'profile_image',
                  'message', 'photo', 'read', 'automated_reply', 'created_at')
```

Request:

```
POST /api/v2/chatmessagestest/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8001
Authorization: Token 457d23ce2e9699f8a911c2230972cf44a09c94b8Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="room"

1
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message_image"; filename="profile.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Error:

```
web_1       | "POST /api/v2/chatmessages/ HTTP/1.1" 500 138694
web_1       | Internal Server Error: /api/v2/chatmessages/
web_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
web_1       |     self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework_tracking/base_mixins.py", line 29, in initial
web_1       |     self.log['data'] = self._clean_data(request.body)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework_tracking/base_mixins.py", line 163, in _clean_data
web_1       |     data = data.decode()
web_1       | UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 284: invalid start byte
```

I've searched the web for a while now and haven't found any suggestions that fix the issue.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an old library dependency that we hadn't updated in our `requirements.txt`

Bumping `drf-tracking==1.5.0` to `drf-api-tracking==1.7.5` fixed the issue as it brought in changes addressing this issue: https://github.com/aschn/drf-tracking/issues/125